# Postfix under fedora 35 does not show mail configuration menu

Tags: fedora, postfix

Following this guide for Fedora 35: https://gist.github.com/raelgc/6031274

```
sudo yum install postfix
```

does not produce the following menu:

```
General type of mail configuration: 

No configuration
Internet Site
Internet with smarthost
Satellite system
Local only
```

With Ubuntu I'd use `dpkg-reconfigure postfix` but there is no such mechanic in Fedora.

How do I get to this menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fedora doesn't have this feature: it's a special script written by Debian developers. You can probably copy and run it but it may not work because different distros may use/have quite different configuration files and store them at different locations.

Comment: That makes sense. I will switch to Ubuntu server so that I can continue the tutorial, thank you.